# Изменение условий sql запроса?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Доброго времени суток!
есть у меня такой запрос

```
$tmpall = mysql_query("SELECT id, namenews, imgfile, description FROM news WHERE class='nw' ORDER BY id DESC",$db);
```

но мне надо что бы в зависимости от обстоятельств условие WHERE менялось к примеру там было не 1 сравнение а 2 или 3 тоесть менять этот участок запроса - как такое можно сделать??

возможен ли вариант на подобии того что бы вносить пред запросом условия в переменную к примеру $zapros = "class='nw' || id='9' || imgfile='$file'";

а потом выодит как то так??

$tmpall = mysql_query("SELECT id, namenews, imgfile, description FROM news WHERE <?php echo $zapros; ?> ORDER BY id DESC",$db); ??? думаю понятно что я имею в виду (данный псевдо код нужен только для наглядности))

Comment: @DanteLoL

     $tmpall = mysql_query("SELECT id, namenews, imgfile, description FROM news WHERE ${zapros} ORDER BY id DESC",$db);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Собираешь переменную $where по частям:

$where = ''; //предопределяю
if (!empty($class)) $where .= ' OR class='.$class;
if (!empty($id))    $where .= ' OR id='.$id;
if (!empty($file))  $where .= ' OR imgfile='.$file;

//после этого уже можно выполнить запрос
$tmpall = mysql_query("SELECT id, namenews, imgfile, description FROM news (!empty($where) ? 'WHERE 1'.$where : '') ORDER BY id DESC",$db);
```